# Post Request in Clojure with clj-http - body not accepted?

Tags: post, clojure, clj-http

With my post request the API documentation for the CRM I wish to post too requires that I post a JSON file.

The JSON file is a multi-level file which is seen in clojure as a persistent array map.

My code to post is:

```
(def contacts (http/post "https://api.close.com/api/v1/data/search" 
           {:basic-auth [api ""]
            :body closeFilter 
            }))
```

CloseFilter represents the mutli-level JSON I wish to post.

However, I get the following error:

`class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to class [B (clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

What mistake am I making here?

### Update

I am recreating a program I have in Javascript. Posting the same file works perfectly.

### Update 2 - MRE

I am still struggling with this so here is an example of my code.

My code starts off by requiring the packages I need:

```
(ns schedule-emails.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as http]
            [clojure.data.json :as json]
            [cheshire.core :refer :all]))
```

Then, I parse a local JSON file from my file system into the app. The JSON. This returns a map of maps with embedded vectors.

```
(def closeFilter
  (json/read-str
   (slurp "URL TO LOCAL FILE")))
```

Finally, I want to post this information from the local file to the software:

```
def contacts (http/post "API URL HERE"
           {:accept :json
            :as :json
            :content-type :json
            :basic-auth [api ""]
            :body closeFilter}))
```

However, I get the following error:

`class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to class [B (clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

I also tried the suggested solution below but i'm getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clj-http` does not on it's own negotiate with some backend what it
expects and coerce the transferred data "automatically".  You can
however configure, that in the case of JSON, so some data with the
proper content-type will be transformed both from the body into the
request, and back to data from the response using JSON.

1. So you usually want the following things
   in the request:

   ```clj
   {:as :auto
    :coerce :always
    :content-type :application/json
    :body ...
    ; your own additional stuff...
    }
   ```

   So add a mime-type, so both clj-http knows what to do and the backend knows
   what it gets.

   See [input coercion](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#input-coercion) and
   [output coercion](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#output-coercion)
2. and you have to make sure, that the means to make it actually working
   are there.  This means, that you have added `cheshire` as dependency.
   See [optional dependencies](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#optional-dependencies)

Another option of course is do deal with this yourself.  So you would
have add a library, that can create JSON from/to a string or stream, the
the `content-type` and transform the body/response.

Comment: Thank you. I added the coerce and added `:as :json` and the content type. But im still getting the same error. For context, the `closeFilter` comes from a variable that reads the JSON file from the file system.

Comment: Have you added cheshire?

Comment: Yeah, I had cheshire installed from the start.

Comment: Then I suggest you provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

To use the built-in JSON coercion for a request body you need to set `:form-params` instead of `:body`, along with `:content-type :json`:

```clj
;; Send form params as a json encoded body (POST or PUT)
(client/post "http://example.com" {:form-params {:foo "bar"} :content-type :json})
```

Details: https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#post

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from clj-http/post probably because the type of `closeFilter` is neither a `HttpEntity` instance, a Java byte-array (`[B`), or a java.lang.String.  From `3.12.3`:
https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/d92be158230e8094436f415324d96f2bd7cf95f7/src/clj_http/core.clj#L605C1-L611C54

The accepted answer assumes you want to automate coercion. I tend to perform JSON serialization manually to a `body` value when using clj-http:

```clj
(client/post
 "http://example.com"
 {:content-type :json
  :body (-> form ch/generate-string})
```